# convert apache rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

Can you help to covert these rewrites?

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /         
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(payment|admin|provider|partner)/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [L]
```

I tried some online converted and they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location ~ (payment|admin|provider|partner)/ { 

} 
location / { 
  if (!-e $request_filename) { 
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /dispatcher.php break; 
  } 
}
```